# How to escape from this regex with the output?

Tags: regex, sed

I want the domain name to be separated for some other calculation.

**Input:** `example.uk.db.com`

**Expected output**: `uk.db.com`

when I give backslash \ it totally escapes without the return.

```
sed '/\.[a-zA-Z].*//'
```

This matches `.uk.db.com`.

Comment: What does "when I give backslash \ it totally escapes without the return" mean? Please show the whole code.

Comment: Can you add sample input and expected output?

Comment: input - "example.uk.db.com"  , expected output is - "uk.db.com"

Comment: `sed 's/^[^.]*\.//'` @VelumaniM

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, am new to sed in one of my code i need the domain name comparison from a list of files. So am trying to compare the domain name to manipulate the execution. when I executed \.[a-zA-Z].* it matches the string but the output says "An unescaped delimiter".

Comment: @VelumaniM Please add all clarifications to the question itself.

Comment: @Kent, Thank you it works as expected. cheers.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - sure i'll give clear details going forward. thank you Wiktor.

Answer (score 0):

The expression you use matches after the first dot including it.

Match up to and including the first dot:

```
sed 's/^[^.]*\.//' <<< "example.uk.db.com"
```

Result: `uk.db.com`.

`^[^.]*\.` will match any characters different from the period symbol up to and including the first dot and this text will get removed.